# PhoneGap Build : new .ipa gets "redundant binary upload" error using Application Loader and iTunes connect

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, phonegap-build, application-loader

The other day I successfully uploaded the first version of my PhoneGap app to iTunes connect using Application Loader.

In my config i had version="0.1.12" which is what appeared in application loader when i pushed it up to connect (deliver your app window).

After some beta testing using testflight some bugs were found and I needed to make some changes before I "Submitted for review".

After resolving all bugs I incremented my version number to 0.2.0, re-uploaded the code to Build, and re-built the ipa in Build as I'd done previously.

In PG Build the version number did indeed increase to 0.2.0 however when I try and upload the new .ipa using Application Loader the build number always states 0.1.12 (Deliver your app window) resulting in an error:

> ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '0.1.12' for train '0.1.12'" at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset

I've seen a couple of threads on SO recommending incrementing the version number which I've done many times but to no avail. It is also worth pointing out I'm not using xcode just Build and Application Loader.

Comment: I'm facing same problem, How you solved this.

Comment: @Gowri yes i restarted my laptop and funnily enough it was fine